# Azure Function returns 500 internal server error

Tags: azure, function, xamarin.forms, http-status-code-500

I am trying to work an exercise from the book "Mastering Xamarin.Forms" 3rd edition. I have followed the instructions in the book to add a function app through the portal.

The run.csx file looks like this:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray entryTableInput, IAsyncCollector<Entry> entryTableOutput, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation(req.Method);
    if (req.Method == "GET")
    {
        return (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult(entryTableInput);
    }
    var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    var entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entry>(requestBody);

    if (entry != null)
    {
                await entryTableOutput.AddAsync(entry);
        return (ActionResult) new OkObjectResult(entry);
    }
    return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid entry request.");
}
public class Entry
{
    public string Id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    // Required for Table Storage entities
    public string PartitionKey => "ENTRY";
    public string RowKey => Id;
}
```

The function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "entryTableOutput",
      "tableName": "entry",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "entryTableInput",
      "tableName": "entry",
      "take": 50,
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

I'm using Postman to test the request. Both GET and POST return 500 internal server error. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: You should link your function to an Application Insights instance and look at the error there

Comment: From Application Insights, I see this error: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext

Comment: Try looking at the host logs in Kudu, often the can give some insight into what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found the answer you were looking for, but, in case anyone else comes across this post in future (like I did when I had the same error, and not having used Azure before)...

After you have created the *Function* (***entry*** as per the code listed above) you need to select the *Integration* option and specify the following:

**Inputs**
Binding Type: *Azure Table Storage*
Table parameter name: *entryTableInput*
Table name: *entry*
Storage account connection: *AzureWebJobsStorage*

**Outputs**
Binding Type: *Azure Table Storage*
Table parameter name: *entryTableOutput*
Table name: *entry*
Storage account connection: *AzureWebJobsStorage*

Also, go to the *Storage Account* that is created as part of setting the Azure function up, and under *Tables*, create a blank table called ***entry***.

You should then find that you can use Postman to test the API as per the instructions in the book.

Comment: I've created this blank table you suggested and that seems to have solved my problem (I was having a similar pb to this post). Also, your tip on these input/outputs by going to the `Integration` was useful to me to spot a spelling mistake I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try running the function locally and setting breakpoints within the function. You can then use Postman to trigger the function, step through with the debugger, and see what the problem is. When deploying an Azure Function to Azure, I'd also suggest enabling Application Insights, which you can use to see the details of exceptions that are thrown.